# ms ajax hover extender error "An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

It is obvious that the control and the extender are in the same update panel. Yet, a "An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends" error occurs.

**NOTE:** The user control is declared within an UpdatePanel on the page using it. That makes the UpdatePanel in the user control "nested".

The following code is in the Asp.Net UserControl:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="0px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="hoverMenuUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <ajaxtoolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="extensionActionHoverMenuExtender" runat="server"
                        PopupControlID="extensionActionHoverMenu" PopupPosition="Left" HoverCssClass="popupHover"
                        TargetControlID="extensionActionHoverMenu" OffsetX="5" PopDelay="50" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="extensionActionHoverMenu" runat="server" CssClass="modalDialogPanel"
                        Style="display: none; height: 200px; width: 300px; padding: 5px;">
                        <div style="border-color: #3A362C; padding: 2px; border-right-style: solid; border-right-width: thin;
                            float: left;">
                            <div class="title">
                                Reserve Extension: &nbsp
                                <asp:Label ID="extensionToReserveLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ConsolidatedPhoneExtensionPK") %>' />
                            </div>
                            <div id="userType" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 5px; height: 80px;
                                width: 200px; background-color: #E2DDBA; margin-bottom: 8px;">
                                User Type:
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="reservedUserTypeRadioButtonList" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Selected="true" Text="999/988" Value="Employee" />
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                Employee No:<asp:TextBox ID="reserveEmployeeNo" runat="server" OnTextChanged="reserveEmployeeNo_TextChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <asp:Label ID="employeeNameDisplayLabel" runat="server" />
                                <asp:Label ID="reserveUserMessageAreaLabel" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <asp:Button ID="selectButton" runat="server" Text="View" CommandName="Select" Width="75px" />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <asp:Button ID="reserveButton" runat="server" Text="Reserve" CommandName="Reserve"
                                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ConsolidatedPhoneExtensionPK") %>' Width="75px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="reserveEmployeeNo" EventName="TextChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a panel with an ID of "popup" (it can be anthing you like though). In this panel place any buttons or what ever you want, this will be your popup menu. Set your PopupControlID to "popup".

Your TargetControlID should be the ID of the panel you want the manu to popup in (extensionActionHoverMenu?).

Answer (score 0):

`PopupControlID` and `TargetControlID` are the same.  Your `TargetControlID` should be some other form element.

[HoverMenu Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/HoverMenu/HoverMenu.aspx):

> - TargetControlID - The control that the extender is targeting. When
>     the mouse cursor is over this control,
>     the hover menu popup will be
>     displayed.
> - PopupControlID - The ID of the control to display when mouse is over
>     the target control. In this case, it's
>     just a simple panel with two links:

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's not about the updatepanel but about other items of the toolkit.
I got this message while using the FilteredTextBoxExtender. The control defined int the TargetControlID was in a different updatepanel.